# Pathfinder encounter building checklist

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design

I have been GMing in pathfinder for a little under a year now and I have recently realized that I have not been taking full advantage of certain aspects of combat encounters such as terrain effects and such.

I looked online for a checklist of possible things such as, difficult terrain, special objects and hazard that you can add to an encounter but all I found was hero lab and encounter generators which is not what I want.

Is there a manual checklist that I can use to make sure I have at least thought of each mechanical part of an encounter, such as rough terrain or hazards?

It should be easy to copy so I can use it for multiple encounters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly any environment you can imagine can add to a fight.

As such there is no exhaustive list, however the following resources (it was resources that was requested) should be of use:

- [What encounter features make low CR enemies challenging?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/what-encounter-features-make-low-cr-enemies-challenging)
- [How do I design exciting, fun boss fights for my players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/how-do-i-design-exciting-fun-boss-fights-for-my-players)
- [How do I build interesting dungeons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/how-do-i-build-interesting-dungeons)
- [Tips for making encounters more interesting](http://dungeonsmaster.com/2012/03/tips-for-making-encounters-more-interesting/)

But possibly the most comprehensive aid on this topic I've found is this;

- [Encounter Handbook](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Iaav8f7Iuk84DsT0buaUX737CWI83wWIlP-JD1spsyc/edit)